# tracking entity changes with overriden saveChanges method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity

I have implemented an overriden save changes method to capture changes made to our entities in to a database table. It works great in some situations, but I have found that in one situation it falls flat.

```
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var modifiedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries()
            .Where(p => p.State == EntityState.Modified).ToList();
```

In my dbcontext I am checking for a modified entity here and then later on comparing its pre-update value against its updated value like so:

```
  originalValue = change.OriginalValues[prop].ToString();
  currentValue = change.CurrentValues[prop].ToString();
```

This works great in situations where I name drop fields in the update code like this:

```
  entity.property1 = entityUpdated.property1;
```

My issue comes where we have a big data set and don't wish to set all fields out like that. We tend to use this to update these bigger entities:

```
_entities.Entry(updatedEntity).State = EntityState.Modified
```

When it comes to checking these, the change.OriginalValues[prop] has "lost" the original value in favour of the new value - I assume due to setting the state on it. that then fools the comparison of original and current and no change is logged.

Is there anything I can do in my update code to avoid having to set every single property individually? I love the ease of EntityState.Modified but if it kills my change tracking we clearly can't use it.

Many thanks

Comment: Before doing `.State = EntityState.Modified` I guess you attach that entity to context with `Attach`?

Comment: would I be attaching the pre modified entity or the modified entity?

Comment: No I ask if you do that or not?

Comment: Ah sorry, no I wasn't attaching prior to the .State = EntityState.Modified . I have noticed that if I round trip the DB and get the original entity out and attach it prior to .State = EntityState.Modified my change track will work. Shame it requires another DB call though.

Comment: If you don't attach, that means you have entity, then you modify some properties (how?), then you set state to `EntityState.Modified`?

Comment: So i have a razor view that takes an existing entity as a model which the user can change via input fields. When the form is submitted, the controller passes that changed object up to my repository via my service where EntityState.Modified is applied and the object saved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138091/discussion-between-iain-bruce-and-evk).